# Insert a scrollview into another scrollview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

Is it to possible insert a scrollview into another scrollview? I noticed that the contained scrollview is freezed and do not move when I scroll the main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIScrollView` can be contained in another `UIScrollView`. If the contained scrollView's content size is not greater than the parent scrollView then it'll remain frozen.

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can, UIScrollView inherits from UIView and you can use it's **addSubview** method.